# How to apply configuration after replacing Routing Engine(RE) for CISCO7609-S?

Tags: cisco, routing

Senario:
I have the backup configuration file. But I don't any USB drive or compact flash card. After replacing the Routing Engine, I tried to copy/paste the configs (around 12k lines) from the console terminal, however, it seems pasting the configs broke the buffer.

Question: what's the best way to apply the configs to the router?

Comment: What app did you use to paste the config in?  Hyperterminal is notorious for doing that.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

Your options are pretty limited, but I see two possible solutions.

1. Increase the baud rate for your serial connection. This will allow higher throughput on your serial link.
2. Temporarily set up a /30 link between your laptop and the Cat7600 and use a local tftp server to move the file into the startup config. If the RSP has a MGMT interface on the front you can use this.

Answer (score 2):

When you tried pasting that many rows of config it was sent faster than the router could handle. You need to use a terminal client that supports using a line send delay.

If you use a line delay of maybe 10 ms then the router should be able to handle it fine. You can also put a character delay if that is needed.

Comment: I use iTerm(2) on the Mac for this, it has a 'special paste' function of paste slow, allows me to paste in long configs on serial connected devices without killing the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If buffer size is an issue, and you have physical access to the Router (which I know I am assuming that you do), set up a TFTP session between the 7609 and your laptop.  Then you can dump the config file that way to the router.